# Using two instances of AVSpeechSynthesizer simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

I would like to use two instances of AVSpeechSynthesizer simultaneously.

```
let firstSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let secondSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

func foo() {
   let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Foo Foo Foo Foo Foo")
   utterance.rate = 0.4
   utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
   firstSynthesizer.speak(utterance)
}

func bar() {
   let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar")
   utterance.rate = 0.4
   utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
   secondSynthesizer.speak(utterance)
}
```

When I call `foo()` and `bar()`, the texts are not read at the same time but one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to use two instances of AVSpeechSynthesizer simultaneously.

It's definitely not possible  in iOS 12, **only one speech synthesis is vocally processed at a time**.

However, [an audio session](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18236.html#Basics) can be played together with the speech synthesis.